# how do I initialize a float to its max/min value?

Tags: c++, primitive-types

How do I hard code an absolute maximum or minimum value for a float or double? I want to search out the max/min of an array by simply iterating through and catching the largest.

There are also positive and negative infinity for floats, should I use those instead? If so, how do I denote that in my code?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) which is defined in `<limits>` to  find the minimum or maximum value of types (As long as a specialization exists for the type). You can also use it to retrieve infinity (and put a `-` in front for negative infinity).

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
```

As noted in the comments, `min()` returns the lowest possible positive value. In other words the positive value closest to 0 that can be represented. The lowest possible value is the negative of the maximum possible value.

There is of course the [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and min_element functions (defined in `<algorithm>`) which may be a better choice for finding the largest or smallest value in an array.

Comment: How do i use this exactly? What do i need to include? I don't think I've used something like this before.

Comment: Hmm...that max element function would have been very useful...this is what happens when you learn coding on your own and not formally. You end up reinventing the wheel 50 times over. This is just like the last time i learned about ceil(). Thank you.

Comment: @Yacoby, you might want to clarify that numeric_limits<float>::min() doesn't mean most negative value, it means smallest positive.

Comment: What if the type T is not known at initialization time, and the array is unavailable (online algorithms)? numeric_limits<T>::max() is a good initialization for the min value, but what about min? I fear that the negation of numeric_limits<T>::max() will not work properly for integral types, just for floats

Comment: @killogre: C++11 added `numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`, which returns the lowest (negative) value possible for the type to solve this problem.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` does *not* give the smallest positive value that can be represented; it gives the smallest *normal* single-precision floating point number.  There are also *subnormal* numbers between zero and this number.  In particular, `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` gives `1.17549e-38` but the smallest representable subnormal float is `nextafterf(0.0f, 1.0f) == 1.4013e-45f`.

Answer (score 64):

You can either use `-FLT_MAX` (or `-DBL_MAX`) for the maximum magnitude negative number and `FLT_MAX` (or `DBL_MAX`) for positive. This gives you the range of possible float (or double) values.

You probably don't want to use `FLT_MIN`; it corresponds to the smallest magnitude positive number that can be represented with a float, not the most negative value representable with a float.

`FLT_MIN` and `FLT_MAX` correspond to `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`.

Comment: I think I'll use this version actually, its simpler to remember and makes more scene to me. Integers i can just initialize using hexadecimal. Though, best answer still stays because the answer also introduced me to some new extremely useful functions.

Comment: "[`FLT_MIN`] corresponds to the smallest magnitude positive number that can be represented with a float" - **This is not true**.  It's the smallest *normal* number. There are also subnormal numbers.

Comment: You want `FLT_TRUE_MIN` for the actual smallest possible float, which corresponds to `std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()`

Comment: Both FLT_MAX and FLT_MIN are defined in <float.h> header.

Comment: Does the value of `FLT_MAX` change according to the platform?

Answer (score 17):

There's no real need to initialize to smallest/largest possible to find the smallest/largest in the array:

```
double largest = smallest = array[0];
for (int i=1; i<array_size; i++) {
    if (array[i] < smallest)
        smallest = array[i];
    if (array[i] > largest0
        largest= array[i];
}
```

Or, if you're doing it more than once:

```
#include <utility>

template <class iter>
std::pair<typename iter::value_type, typename iter::value_type> find_extrema(iter begin, iter end) {
    std::pair<typename iter::value_type, typename iter::value_type> ret;
    ret.first = ret.second = *begin;
    while (++begin != end) {
        if (*begin < ret.first)
           ret.first = *begin;
        if (*begin > ret.second)
           ret.second = *begin;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

The disadvantage of providing sample code -- I see others have already suggested the same idea.

Note that while the standard has a min_element and max_element, using these would require scanning through the data twice, which could be a problem if the array is large at all. Recent standards have addressed this by adding a `std::minmax_element`, which does the same as the `find_extrema` above (find both the minimum and maximum elements in a collection in a single pass).

Edit: Addressing the problem of finding the smallest non-zero value in an array of unsigned: observe that unsigned values "wrap around" when they reach an extreme. To find the smallest non-zero value, we can subtract one from each for the comparison. Any zero values will "wrap around" to the largest possible value for the type, but the *relationship* between other values will be retained. After we're done, we obviously add one back to the value we found.

```
unsigned int min_nonzero(std::vector<unsigned int> const &values) { 
    if (vector.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    unsigned int temp = values[0]-1;
    for (int i=1; i<values.size(); i++)
        if (values[i]-1 < temp)
            temp = values[i]-1;
    return temp+1;
}
```

Note this still uses the first element for the initial value, but we still don't need any "special case" code -- since that will wrap around to the largest possible value, any non-zero value will compare as being smaller. The result will be the smallest nonzero value, or 0 if and only if the vector contained no non-zero values.

Comment: But you get a +1 for it from me!

Comment: I initlize to max mins because sometimes i want the smallest non zero value (in an unsigned integer case for example, my data tends to have a lot of uninteresting zeros). It just seems to make sense to me to initialize it rather than preform extra checks to ensure the first element is not zero.

Comment: @Faken: Even then you can define a comparison function that treats zero as the largest possible value, so you can still use `std::min_element`: `bool less_ignoring_zero(unsigned a, unsigned b) { if (a == 0) return false; if (b == 0) return true; return a < b; }`

Comment: @Jerry: C++0x will add minmax_element to address the problem you mention. (But then it won't be possible to ignore zeros...)

Comment: What if the first element is not available at the time of initialization? This happens a lot in online processing (as in boost::accumulators)

Comment: @killogre: In that case, initializing your minimum to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` and your maximum to `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is certainly a reasonable possibility.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: this doesn't work for floating point types, because min() returns the lowest positive value. for floating types I currently initialize with -max(), but this is wrong for unsigned integral types

Comment: @killogre: Oops -- yeah, I know that, and always forget it. You end up with an ugly condition based on `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer`.

Comment: There's a subtle problem with this approach for floating point values that might be NaN.  If the first element of the array is NaN, then it will return NaN as the min and max.  If any other element is NaN however, that element will be ignored.  So the result becomes dependent on the order of the values in the array, which can lead to suprises.  Initializing the loop with -inf/inf instead of the first element of the array does not have this problem.

Answer (score 6):

To manually find the minimum of an array you don't need to know the minimum value of float:

```
float myFloats[];
...
float minimum = myFloats[0];
for (int i = 0; i < myFloatsSize; ++i)
{
  if (myFloats[i] < minimum)
  {
    minimum = myFloats[i];
  }
}
```

And similar code for the maximum value.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest that you initialize your "max and min so far" variables not to infinity, but to the first number in the array?